# Elegant filtering of DataGrid (WPF) in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I want this scenario:

1. Using Entity Framework bind the DataGrid (WPF) to some collection of entities.
2. Now, I would like to have one TextBox for each column and filter the rows online as user changes the TextBoxes' content.

So, specifically, data is loaded and bound only once. There would be around 1000 rows.

Thank you in advance!
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use ICollectionView.Filter to create your own filter.

look at [this](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=31) or [this](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/).

Answer (score 0):

I know I may not be answering to your requirement directly but this may be of some help to you or your organization. Instead of developing something from scratch, you can use something that is already developed and tested. Have a look at [DevExpress DxGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Grid/) or Filtering page [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Grid/filter.xml)

Hope that helps. I have DevExpress controls in past and they are really awesome

Comment: Thank you, but I need to find out how can it be done. Not interested in third-party components.